# uploaded images in jdk bin folder can not be found in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, image-uploading, imagesource

I've created a folder **A** in path

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\staticContents\pics\A

I put images in folder **A** and then went to

> C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\conf

path and open server.xml file and changed as follows:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
<context docBase="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/staticContents" path="/rop/static"/>
```

Now I am using this code to show images in **A** folder:

```
<div class="img-wrap">
<img  style='padding: 10px' width='300' height='200' class='m' mpath='13473.png' src="http://localhost/rop/static/pics/A/13473.png"></div>
```

But the image can not be found.

Comment: you probaby also need to specify xmlValidation="false" and autoDeploy=“false” since you do not have a valid war. Also, does your tomcat listen on port 80, not 8080? And lastly, why would you chose such a uncommon location for your static content?

Comment: I set xmlValidation="false" and autoDeploy=“false” for <host> tag and my tomcat listen on port 80. but it says "Error 404 Page not found."

Comment: @RogerLindsjö what is the best location for uploaded images?

Comment: Not sure what you are doing wrong, installed a clean tomcat 9, changed to port 18080 and added <Context docBase="/Users/roger/test/static" path="/stuff"/>, put an image in /Users/roger/test/static which I could access via http://localhost:18080/stuff/image.png

Comment: Most common is to put the content inside the actual war you are building, or at least have a resources folder which you point to. To put static content inside a specific JDK installation is very uncommon.